# Spring RequestScope bean not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to learn more about Spring bean scopes for use in a project.  I've created a few test classes, and I am not getting the behavior I'd expect.

I created the following component, and I would like this bean to last for only the duration of the HTTP request.

```
@Component
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class UserDataContainer {
    
    public int requestCount = 0;

}
```

The following controller uses that component.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserDataContainer userData;

    @GetMapping
    public String get(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("prev", userData.requestCount);
        
        userData.requestCount++;
        
        model.addAttribute("curr", userData.requestCount);
        
        return "test";
    }

}
```

My trouble is, it doesn't seem that a new instance of UserDataContainer is created for each request.  Whenever I load this page, I see that the values of "prev" and "curr" keep incrementing, instead of resetting to 0 at the start of each request.  Am I misunderstanding how this is supposed to work, or is something not implemented correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that the request scoped bean is not invoked directly by your controller.

Instead the controller uses a proxy to invoke the request scoped bean (in this case, the proxy is a cglib one based on your proxy mode annotation, ie: `ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS`

The proxy only wraps around **methods** of the request scoped bean and not it's **variables**.

So in short, encapsulate the instance variable of your request scoped bean into a method and call that method from the Controller.

something like this:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class UserDataContainer {

   private int requestCount = 0;
   public int incrementRequestCount(){
        requestCount++;
        return requestCount;
   }

   public int getRequestCount(){
         return requestCount;
   }
}
```

then in your Controller, just invoke the public methods

```
@GetMapping
public String get(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("prev", userData.getRequestCount());

    model.addAttribute("curr", userData.incrementRequestCount());
    
    return "test";
}
```